# How turn a word in my php code a specific colour, and moving a comma issue

Tags: php

I'm not a very competent coder as I'm very new, and I really need some help with this one.

The code below pulls data from a taxonomy on Wordpress. It posts it on the page as:

**Fruits offered: Apples, Oranges, Pears, Strawberries**

Now every listing has to offer Apples in this scenario, this is mandatory so it's typed right into the $fruit_links. Now my issue is that if no other fruits are offered, the comma at the end of Apples needs to not be there. How do I go about adjust the code to make the comman after Apples only appear if other fruits are offered? Also, I need to change the color of just the word Apples, how would I do this?

I bolded the Apples below to highlight which one I'm talking about.

```
$fruit_links = " Fruits offered: **Apples,** ";

$term_list_category = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'fruit_key', array("fields" => "ids"));

$i = 0;

$countC = count($term_list_category);

if ( $countC > 0 ){

    foreach ( $term_list_category as $term_category ) {

        $thisfruit = get_term_by( 'id', $term_category, 'fruit_key');


        $url = '<a class="listing-links" href="/search-results/?fruit='.$thisfruit->{'slug'}.'" title="'.$thisfruit->{'name'}.' - Fruit market listings " >'.$thisfruit->{'name'}.'</a>';

        $i ++;

        $seo .= " " . $thisfruit->{'name'} . "";

        $fruit_links .= " " . $url . "";

        if ($countC > 1 && $countC !== $i) {$fruit_links .= ", ";  $seo .= ", "; }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question (how do I make the word "Apples" red), the answer is CSS (Cascading Style Sheets).

To your second question, we can remove trailing commas by using the `rtrim()` function, or just start without a comma and add a comma every time we concatenate to the end of the string.

Something like this might work for you:

```
<?php

$fruit_links = ' Fruits offered: <span style="color: red;">Apples</span>';
$term_list_category = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'fruit_key', array("fields" => "ids"));
$i = 0;
$countC = count($term_list_category);
if ($countC > 0) {
    foreach ($term_list_category as $term_category) {
        $thisfruit = get_term_by('id', $term_category, 'fruit_key');
        $url = '<a class="listing-links" href="/search-results/?fruit=' . $thisfruit->{'slug'} . '" title="' . $thisfruit->{'name'} . ' - Fruit market listings " >' . $thisfruit->{'name'} . '</a>';
        $i++;
        $seo .= ', ' . $thisfruit->{'name'};
        $fruit_links .= ', ' . $url;
    }
}
```

Some links for you:

[Beginner's CSS tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

[PHP's rtrim() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Comment: Thanks for the help chjohasbrouck! I'm familiar with everything CSS, just didn't realize I could add a span in the php. The comma I was referring to is the one after Apples in $fruit_links, I simply typed it in. The rtrim didn't remove it. I was thinking there would be a code modification that could let me delete the comma typed in beside Apples, and then have the comma appear only if more fruits were offered. Hope that makes sense? :D

Comment: You could just start without the trailing comma, then every time you concatenate a new element to the end of the string, add the comma before it. I updated the code in my answer to show you something like that.

Comment: Perfect, that worked out great except for one little thing. I tried to look in to this myself but I went as far as preg_replace(). The comma that it now places has a white space before it.

Ex: Apples , pears, oranges, etc

Any quick fix to remedy this?

Comment: Is the extra whitespace only showing after "Apples"? If so there's probably just a space left in your code somewhere, maybe near the closing </span> tag in that first string. Just remove the space?

Comment: Awesome! Had a space after the span, you were right. Thanks so much chjohasbrouck! :D